# Python: Issues with dict that contains strings and numbers

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict entitled name_dict with values that are strings and numbers inside of it. Here it is.

```
name_dict={'first': 324/1080*100,'second':484/1823*100,'third':931/2765*100}
```

I am supposed to have the user input a range and if one of the numbers in name_dict is not in the range, then it is supposed to print that number along with the value associated with it. this is my whole program:

```
print('Enter the tolerance range for valid values')
tr=input('ex. If your range is 20-40%, please type as 20 40')
tr_split=tr.split()
tr_int= [int(i) for i in tr_split]
if tr_int[0]<0:
    print('Error. Lower tolerance cannot be less than 0.')
elif tr_int[1]>100:
    print('Error. Higher tolerance cannot be greater than 100.')
elif tr_int[0]>tr_int[1]:
    print('Error. Lower tolerance cannot be greater than higher tolerance.')
name_dict={'first': 324/1080*100,'second':484/1823*100,'third':931/2765*100}
for i in name_dict:
    if i<tr_int[0] or i>tr_int[1]:
        print(name_dict)
```

When I do this I receive this error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

How can I get it to print out the name and number instead of an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
for i in name_dict:
    if i<tr_int[0] or i>tr_int[1]:
        print(name_dict)
```

with

```
for key,value in name_dict.items():
    if not (tr_int[0] < value < tr_int[1]):
        print(key, value)
```

Comment: When I did this, it printed name_dict multiple times at the end instead of just the value.

Comment: @bw61293 I updated answer. Try it please, was the issue fixed?

Comment: yes, but how can I get it to print the name that is associated with that value along with it? like instead of printing '26.549' it will print 'second 26.549'